# in Spring Framework 5.0: Functional Web Framework how to put the newley created entity's id in webflux serverresponse header

Tags: spring, functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

```
 public Mono<ServerResponse> post(ServerRequest request) {
   final Mono<Person> person = request.bodyToMono(Person.class);
   final String id = ????; //replace this with newly inserted //objects id
   return created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("people/" + 
   id).build().toUri())
        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(
                fromPublisher(
                        person.map(p -> new Person(p, 
       id)).flatMap(personManager::save), Person.class));
 }
```

Here i am trying to post a entity to server to be created. i need to insert the newly created object's id into location header of the response .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following a my project in kotlin you can write a code like below:

```
   @Configuration
    class ResumeRoute {

        @Bean
        fun resumeRoutes(@Value("\${baseServer:http://localhost:8080}") baseServer: String, resumeRepository: ResumeRepository) = router {

        POST("/resume")
        {


   it.principal().flatMap {
            resumeRepository.save(Resume.emptyResume(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), it.name, Language.EN)).toMono()
        }.flatMap { created(URI("${baseServer}/resume/${it.id}")).build() }
    }

}
```

}

even if this is kotlin and not java version the important thing here is that you should before have your entity in order to get the id and then use this for create the server response

therefore your code should be like below:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> post(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Person.class)
            .map(personManager::save)
            .flatMap(savedPerson ->
                    created((UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("people/" + savedPerson.getId()).build().toUri()))
                            .body(fromObject(savedPerson)));
}
```

I hope that this can help you